# Como usar en un programa de Python un archivo .ui

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Tecnicamente ya el archivo no es .ui, pero lo era cuando lo hice con Qtdesigner, luego lo convertí a .py, pero aun no sé como vincularlo correctamente a mi archivo main.py para comenzar a programar las funciones de cada elemento.
los archivos son main.py, Principal.py(donde estan los formularios y botones) y Almacen.py donde hay dos pantallas que muestran toda la informacion guardada por medio de Principal.py.
Alguien me puede explicar detalladamente como se hace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo una guía en Español que a mi en su día me ayudo mucho y resuelve tu duda! https://medium.com/@hektorprofe/primeros-pasos-en-pyqt-5-y-qt-designer-programas-gr%C3%A1ficos-con-python-6161fba46060